# Ant Design Table Filter parameter enables checkbox on only one filter array element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I am making a table which is populated by data from the backend. The issue is a UI issue. The filter works just fine. However, when I click on the filter icon, it shows the three elements from the filter array but only the first option has checkbox besides it. That checkbox corresponds to the third item of the filter array!

I do not know how to disable check box for all elements or to enable checkboxes for each element since the onFilter is a built in method for antd tables. Here is my code below.

```
import "antd/dist/antd.css";

import { Table } from "antd"
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { transactionTableColumns } from "../../Variables/Variables"
import styles from "../HeaderComponent/DashBoardComponent/Dashboard.module.css";


const TransactionTableComponent = (props) => {

    
    const [filteredInfo, setFilteredInfo] = useState(null)

    useEffect(() => {
        debugger
        setFilteredInfo({});
    }, [])

    useEffect(() => {
        debugger
    }, [filteredInfo])

    const handleChange = (pagination, filters) => {
        setFilteredInfo(filters);
    }

    const transactionTableColumns = [
        {
            title: 'Transaction ID',
            dataIndex: 'TransactionId',
            key: 'TransactionId',
            width: 150,
            sorter: (a, b) => a.TransactionId - b.TransactionId,

        },
        {
            title: 'Transaction Amount',
            dataIndex: 'TransactionAmount',
            key: 'TransactionAmount',
            width: 150,
            sorter: (a, b) => a.TransactionAmount - b.TransactionAmount,
            ellipsis: true,
        },
        {
            title: 'Date',
            dataIndex: 'TransactionDate',
            key: 'TransactionDate',
            width: 150,
            sorter: (a, b) => a.TransactionDate - b.TransactionDate,
        },
        {
                title: "TransactionType",
                dataIndex: "TransactionType",
                key: "TransactionType",
                filters: [
                  { text: "Deposit", value: "DEPOSIT" },
                  { text: "Withdrawl", value: "WITHDRAWL" },
                  { text: "Bill Payment", value: "BILLPAYMENT" }
                ],
                onFilter: (value, record) => record.TransactionType.includes(value),
        },
        {
            title: 'CNIC',
            dataIndex: 'RiderCNIC',
            width: 150,
            key: 'RiderCNIC',
            sorter: (a, b) => a.RiderCNIC - b.RiderCNIC,
        },
        {
            title: 'Transaction Time',
            dataIndex: 'RiderCNIC',
            width: 150,
            key: 'RiderCNIC',
            sorter: (a, b) => a.RiderCNIC - b.RiderCNIC,
        }
    ];

    return (
        <Table
            className={styles.RiderTable}
            columns={transactionTableColumns}
            dataSource={props.transactionTableData}
            // pagination={{ pageSize: 50 }}
            size={'middle'}
            scroll={{ y: 240 }}
            // pagination={{ position: [showPagination.bottom] }}
            onChange={handleChange}

        />
    )
}

export default TransactionTableComponent
```

[image: Note how there is only one checkbox next to the "Deposit" which is the first item of the filters array but when I click on it it actually selects the Bill Payment]

Comment: For me the same code worked without issues. The only difference I can see from copying your code is that i did copy your imported styles. Have you tried without that?

Comment: Yes, I tried that too. It made no difference.

Comment: Can you check if removing styles `../HeaderComponent/DashBoardComponent/Dashboard.module.css` helps?